# How to create query with multiple left joins that sorts the right sides by date across all of them using Peewee

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I need to sort a query using multiple joins by the date of **any** of the right tables - most recent first.

So, borrowing from the Peewee documentation assume I have a User with table Tweets and table Facebook posts.
How do I create a query that allows me to list all Activity (Tweets and Posts) by a user, ordered by date so all activity is in order of timestamp whether it is a Tweet or a Post?

```
import datetime
from peewee import *


db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = TextField()

    @property
    def tweets_date_desc (self)
        return self.tweets.order_by(Tweet.timestamp.desc())


    @property
    def posts_date_desc (self)
        return self.posts.order_by(Facebook.timestamp.desc())


class Tweet(BaseModel):
    content = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')
    


class Facebook(BaseModel):
    content = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='posts')
```

It is easy to display each user, their tweets sorted by date, then their posts sorted by date.

```
user = User.get(User.username == 'huey')
print (user.username)
for t in user.tweets_date_desc:
    print( t.timestamp, t.content)

for p in user.posts_date_desc:
    print( p.timestamp, p.content)
```

But, I have no idea how to get both types sorted by date_of (Tweet OR Post).

Note my real data will not combine into one 'Activity' table like the above simple example could.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would do this with a UNION, e.g.

```
t = (Tweet
     .select(Tweet.content, Tweet.timestamp, User)
     .join(User)
     .where(User.username == 'u1'))
f = (Facebook
     .select(Facebook.content, Facebook.timestamp, User)
     .join(User)
     .where(User.username == 'u1'))

u = (t | f).order_by(SQL('2 desc'))  # Order by 2nd column, timestamp
```

If you are joining instead, you can try to use COALESCE:

```
.order_by(fn.COALESCE(Facebook.timestamp, Tweet.timestamp).desc())
```